# Continuous conversion to text file using Wireshark

Tags: wireshark

What is the procedure to convert captured files to text files on a continuous basis ? Export in *Wireshark* is a manual technique, any way to automate the process ?

Answer (score 1):

Use TShark.

```
tshark -r {capture file}
```

will read the capture file and write out summary lines of the sort that appear in the packet list pane of Wireshark.

```
tshark -V -r {capture file}
```

will read the capture file and write out packet details of the sort that appear in the packet detail pane of Wireshark.